# Convert a black or white only rgb array into a 1 or 0 array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, image, image-processing, physics

I am relatively new to python and I am working with an image containing 'hits' from a particle detector which is totally black and white.

In order to count the number of hits (and later separate the hits from different particles) I need to group the adjacent white pixels.

My code currently ensures the image is only black or white and then tries to use the scipy label function to group the white pixels (this should work as it groups any none 0 values and I made all black pixels have 0's and all white pixels hold 1. However it returns 0 labels and I am unsure why. I think it may be to do with the fact it is not just 1's and 0's but still tuples of lists that I am working with.

Is there a way to create an array simply of 1's or 0's based on whether the pixel is black or white?

```
def analyseImage(self, imPath): 

    img = Image.open(imPath)
    grey = img.convert('L')
    bw = np.asarray(grey).copy()

    #Switches black and white for label to be effective
    bw[bw < 128] = 255    # White
    bw[bw >= 128] = 0 # Black

    lbl, nlbls = label(bw)
    labels = range(1, nlbls + 1)
    coords = [np.column_stack(np.where(lbl == k)) for k in labels]

    imfile = Image.fromarray(bw)
```

Comment: Debugging tip: if you've done processing on an image, write the image out and see if it looks like what you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the line `bw[bw < 128] = 255    # White`, all elements < 128 have been set to 255, which means every element is now >= 128 (since 255 is > 128). The following line then replaces each element with 0, since again all elements are now >= 128.

Try instead:

```
def analyseImage(self, imPath): 

    img = Image.open(imPath)
    grey = img.convert('L')

    #Switches black (0) and white (255) for label to be effective
    bw = np.asarray([255 if x < 128 else 0 for x in grey])

    lbl, nlbls = label(bw)
    labels = range(1, nlbls + 1)
    coords = [np.column_stack(np.where(lbl == k)) for k in labels]

    imfile = Image.fromarray(bw)
```

Alternatively, you could create a copy of your `bw` and use that copy in your comparison with 128:

```
bw2 = bw.copy()
bw[bw2 < 128] = 255
bw[bw2 >= 128] = 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that's really helpful

Comment: Also, according to [this short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKnqECcg6Gw), you may wish to use 180 or 181 as your comparison value, where 180.3 is approx. the sqrt((255^2)/2). And please do select my answer as correct if it solved your problem, thanks.